# openlayers 3 layer visibility or invisibilty

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm trying to display one layer at a time .i have numbers of layer which are trying to display through checkboxes . When i checked the first layer and after that without unchecking the first layer i'll check on the another layer so when the first check box deselect automatically with that deselecting i want to auto remove of first layer also with that unchecked box. But i'm unable to achieve this task .

Here's html code

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="landuse"  />LANDUSE</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="soil" />SOIL</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="slope" />SLOPE</label>
```

This is javascript

```
var landuseLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
     coordinates: [79.14511833527447, 20.987418098133496, 79.2018842619151, 21.050233196545],
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sagy/wms',
          params: {'LAYERS': 'sagy:pachgaon_LULC_Project', transparent: true,  minScale: 8},


        }),
        visible: false
      });


      var soilLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
     coordinates: [79.14567586872208, 20.987841241731143, 79.20165306280867, 21.04983364670783],
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sagy/wms',
          params: {'LAYERS': 'sagy:pachgaon_SOIL_Project', transparent: true,  minScale: 8}

        }),
        visible: false
      });

      var slopeLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
     coordinates: [79.14567586872207, 20.987841241731136, 79.20165306280867, 21.049833646707828],
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sagy/wms',
          params: {'LAYERS': 'sagy:pachgaon_SLOPE_Project', transparent: true,  minScale: 8}

        }),
        visible: false
      });

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          }),landuseLayer,soilLayer, GWPLayer, GPLayer, slopeLayer, transportationLayer, drainageLayer, vector, vectorLayer],
target: document.getElementById('map'),

            view: new ol.View({
            Projection: 'EPSG:4326',
                center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([79.17436, 21.01668]),
  zoom: 5
                                }),
        });
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
var lyrname;
  var layer = {
    landuse: landuseLayer,
    soil: soilLayer,
    slope: slopeLayer,

  }[$(this).attr('id')];
  var extent = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
 lyrname = $(this).attr('id');

if(document.getElementById(lyrname).checked)
{
$('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked',false);
$activeDialogs = $(".ui-dialog:visible").find('.ui-dialog-content');
$activeDialogs.dialog('close');
layer.setVisible(true);
map.getView().setZoom(13);
$('.image1').css('visibility', 'visible');
 if(lyrname== 'landuse'){

$('.image1').css('visibility', 'visible');
$("#dialog").dialog("open");
 }

 else if (lyrname=='soil')
{
$("#dialog1").dialog("open");

}
}else {
          $activeDialogs = $(".ui-dialog:visible").find('.ui-dialog-content');
           $activeDialogs.dialog('close');

            layer.setVisible(false);
        }
});
```

please help me if you have any idea for how to stop overlapping of WMSlayers.

Comment: Check this https://jsfiddle.net/timh06/2Lyhpdgo/ out as an example, if I understand your needs.

Comment: @Timh see like you did i'm also able to get this.. if i take your example  when i check the first layer and without unchecked it i'll check the second .. then first layer should remove automatically...i want one layer active at a time

Comment: Okay sure, just make sure that you set the layers you don't care about to not visible and then filter out the inputs, setting them to checked.  check out: https://jsfiddle.net/timh06/2Lyhpdgo/2/

Comment: @Timh Okay..Thanks its really helpful.